# Count different enteries by year in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count

I have the following table shown in the picture, i want to count all the new codes occuring by years e.g `Year 1972 : New Code: 4, 30 times, New Code: 5 60 times 
Year 1857 New Code: 4, 30 times, New Code: 5, 60 times`.
Preferably save the result in column 1.
[image: The table schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be as simple as:

```
select  Year
,       NewCode
,       count(*)
from    YourTable
group by
        Year
,       NewCode
```

If you want to update the table:

```
update  YourTable yt1
set     Column1 = 
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.Year = yt2.Year
                and yt1.NewCode = yt2.NewCode
        )
```

Comment: Dear Andomar Thank you, can you please tell me 1 more thing if i have to display the Results year wise suchh that following is the output:
`Year/NewCode 1 2 3 4 5 6`

`1832            25      5       6       12      0        13 `

`1833         5       0       0       18      5        1  `